# Program to automate clicking on the new button on a chat website until the username matches certain conditions

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, selenium, webdriver

This is a python program that automates skipping through users on a chat website called 
talkwithstrangers using the `Selenium Webdriver` and `BeautifulSoup` modules of python.

The first part uses selenium to open the browser

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome('C:\SeleniumDrivers\chromedriver.exe')
userName = 'null'
driver.get('https://talkwithstranger.com/talk-to-strangers')
```

The second part is a while loop that run while the username has not met the required conditions,

```
while 'female' not in userName or 'Female' not in userName:
    driver.get('https://talkwithstranger.com/talk-to-strangers')
    html = driver.execute_script("return document.documentElement.innerHTML;")

    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html5lib')
    userVal = soup.find(class_='alert text-center alert-success')
    userNames =  userVal.find_all('b')

    def getName(userNames):
        for name in userNames:
            return name.prettify()

    userName = getName(userNames)
```

The code is running fine but the problem is the efficiency and runtime.

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! Could you share a usage example to see how you put it all together? More context is usually better at Code Review.

Comment: @Mast What I have done here is, I got the full html file from the above-mentioned site and I scraped the required data which is the username and then I made a while loop that keeps on clicking the element new button until the word 'female' in username evaluates to true.

Answer (score 2):

Your third part is wrong, I think.

```
nonCompatible = 'female' not in name
```

will only run against the value of `name` at the time of execution, so `nonCompatible` will end up either `True` or `False`, and won't change unless you reset it elsewhere in the `while` loop.  You may want to either inline it:

```
while 'female' not in name:
    ...
```

or abstract it:

```
def nonCompatible(nym):
    return 'female' not in nym


while nonCompatible(name):
    ...
```

Comment: Thanks for finding the problem. However, I still can't solve even by inlining 'female' not in name in the while loop. The problem is that using selenium webdriver I'm able to get the full html source of the first user only then onwards even if I'm putting it in a while loop the html file remains the same hence the username is also same.

Comment: You've only given code fragments, so it's difficult to tell exactly what's wrong. Also: SO is for fixing problems, this place is for reviewing how well it was fixed.